# Filter or selecting data between two rows in pandas by multiple labels

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, slice

So I have this df or table coming from a pdf tranformation on this way example:

|  | ElementRow | ElementColumn | ElementPage | ElementText | X1 | Y1 | X2 | Y2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 0 | 1 | Emergency Contacts | 917 | 8793 | 2191 | 8878 |
| 2 | 51 | 0 | 1 | Contact | 1093 | 1320 | 1451 | 1388 |
| 3 | 51 | 2 | 1 | Relationship | 2444 | 1320 | 3026 | 1388 |
| 4 | 51 | 7 | 1 | Work Phone | 3329 | 1320 | 3898 | 1388 |
| 5 | 51 | 9 | 1 | Home Phone | 4260 | 1320 | 4857 | 1388 |
| 6 | 51 | 10 | 1 | Cell Phone | 5176 | 1320 | 5684 | 1388 |
| 7 | 51 | 12 | 1 | Priority Phone | 6143 | 1320 | 6495 | 1388 |
| 8 | 51 | 14 | 1 | Contact Address | 6542 | 1320 | 7300 | 1388 |
| 9 | 51 | 17 | 1 | City | 7939 | 1320 | 7300 | 1388 |
| 10 | 51 | 18 | 1 | State | 8808 | 1320 | 8137 | 1388 |
| 11 | 51 | 21 | 1 | Zip | 9134 | 1320 | 9294 | 1388 |
| 12 | 52 | 0 | 1 | Silvia Smith | 1093 | 1458 | 1973 | 1526 |
| 13 | 52 | 2 | 1 | Mother | 2444 | 1458 | 2783 | 1526 |
| 13 | 52 | 7 | 1 | (123) 456-78910 | 5176 | 1458 | 4979 | 1526 |
| 14 | 52 | 10 | 1 | Austin | 7939 | 1458 | 8406 | 1526 |
| 15 | 52 | 15 | 1 | Texas | 8808 | 1458 | 8961 | 1526 |
| 16 | 52 | 20 | 1 | 76063 | 9134 | 1458 | 9421 | 1526 |
| 17 | 52 | 2 | 1 | 1234 Parkside Ct | 6542 | 1458 | 9421 | 1526 |
| 18 | 53 | 0 | 1 | Naomi Smith | 1093 | 2350 | 1973 | 1526 |
| 19 | 53 | 2 | 1 | Aunt | 2444 | 2350 | 2783 | 1526 |
| 20 | 53 | 7 | 1 | (123) 456-78910 | 5176 | 2350 | 4979 | 1526 |
| 21 | 53 | 10 | 1 | Austin | 7939 | 2350 | 8406 | 1526 |
| 22 | 53 | 15 | 1 | Texas | 8808 | 2350 | 8961 | 1526 |
| 23 | 53 | 20 | 1 | 76063 | 9134 | 2350 | 9421 | 1526 |
| 24 | 53 | 2 | 1 | 3456 Parkside Ct | 6542 | 2350 | 9421 | 1526 |
| 25 | 54 | 40 | 1 | End Employee Line | 6542 | 2350 | 9421 | 1526 |
| 25 | 55 | 0 | 1 | Emergency Contacts | 917 | 8793 | 2350 | 8878 |

I'm trying to separate each register by rows taking as a reference ElementRow column and keep the headers from the first rows and then iterate through the other rows after. The column X1 has a reference on which header should be the values. I would like to have the data like this way.

|  | Contact | Relationship | Work Phone | Cell Phone | Priority | ContactAddress | City | State | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Silvia Smith | Mother |  | (123) 456-78910 |  | 1234 Parkside Ct | Austin | Texas | 76063 |
| 2 | Naomi Smith | Aunt |  | (123) 456-78910 |  | 3456 Parkside Ct | Austin | Texas | 76063 |

Things I tried:

To take rows between iterating through the columns. tried to slice taking the first index and the last index but showed this error:

```
emergStartIndex = df.index[df['ElementText'] == 'Emergency Contacts']
emergLastIndex  = df.index[df['ElementText'] == 'End Employee Line']
emerRows_between = df.iloc[emergStartIndex:emergLastIndex]
    
TypeError: cannot do positional indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers [Int64Index([...
```

That way is working with this numpy trick.

```
emerRows_between = df.iloc[np.r_[1:54,55:107]]
emerRows_between
```

but when trying to replace the index showed this:

```
emerRows_between = df.iloc[np.r_[emergStartIndex:emergLastIndex]]
emerRows_between
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I tried iterating row by row like this but in some point the df reach the end and I'm receiving ***index out of bound***.

```
emergencyContactRow1 = df['ElementText','X1'].iloc[emergStartIndex+1].reset_index(drop=True)
emergencyContactRow2 = df['ElementText','X1'].iloc[emergStartIndex+2].reset_index(drop=True)
emergencyContactRow3 = df['ElementText','X1'].iloc[emergStartIndex+3].reset_index(drop=True)
emergencyContactRow4 = df['ElementText','X1'].iloc[emergStartIndex+4].reset_index(drop=True)
emergencyContactRow5 = df['ElementText','X1'].iloc[emergStartIndex+5].reset_index(drop=True)
emergencyContactRow6 = df['ElementText','X1'].iloc[emergStartIndex+6].reset_index(drop=True)
emergencyContactRow7 = df['ElementText','X1'].iloc[emergStartIndex+7].reset_index(drop=True)
emergencyContactRow8 = df['ElementText','X1'].iloc[emergStartIndex+8].reset_index(drop=True)
emergencyContactRow9 = df['ElementText','X1'].iloc[emergStartIndex+9].reset_index(drop=True)
emergencyContactRow10 = df['ElementText','X1'].iloc[emergStartIndex+10].reset_index(drop=True)

frameEmergContact1 = [emergencyContactRow1 , emergencyContactRow2 , emergencyContactRow3, emergencyContactRow4, emergencyContactRow5, emergencyContactRow6, emergencyContactRow7, , emergencyContactRow8,, emergencyContactRow9, , emergencyContactRow10]

df_emergContact1= pd.concat(frameEmergContact1 , axis=1)
df_emergContact1.columns = range(df_emergContact1.shape[1])
```

So how to make this code dynamic or how to avoid the index out of bound errors and keep my headers taking as a reference only the first row after the Emergency Contact row?. I know I didn't try to use the X1 column yet, but I have to resolve first how to iterate through those multiple indexes.

Each iteration from Emergency Contact index to End Employee line belongs to one person or one employee from the whole dataframe, so the idea after capture all those values is to keep also a counter variable to see how many times the data is captured between those two indexes.

Comment: Is your data correct? For Silvia Smith, the "ElementColumn" for Work Phone is 7 but for Naomi Smith, it is 2?

Comment: yes! Thanks for checking was a mistake building the table, fixed. Those are columns coordinates but I think I have to focus more on the X1 values and Y1 to take the correct data.

Comment: Have you had the chance to test my answer? I think it's scalable for larger datasets.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit ugly, but this should do it.  Basically you don't need the first or last two rows, so if you get rid of those, then pivot the X1 and ElemenTex columns you will be pretty close.  Then it's a matter of getting rid of null values and promoting the first row to header.

```
df = df.iloc[1:-2][['ElementTex','X1','ElementRow']].pivot(columns='X1',values='ElementTex')
df = pd.DataFrame([x[~pd.isnull(x)] for x in df.values.T]).T
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
```

Comment: For sure this is a way to go. The thing is the data is uglier than the one posted here and I have to filter it first just taking whatever is between those first rows across all the dataframe and then do the pivot. But thanks for this, for sure this is a way to approach this problem. Just one more question on your code, why that *.T* at the very end of this line  after the parentesis: df = pd.DataFrame([x[~pd.isnull(x)] for x in df.values.T]).T.

Comment: @lug0lug0 It's swapping it from columns to rows to get rid of the nulls then back to columns to go into the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the dataframe into chunks whenever "Emergency Contacts" appears in column "ElementText"
2. Parse each chunk into the required format
3. Append to the output

```
import numpy as np
list_of_df = np.array_split(data, data[data["ElementText"]=="Emergency Contacts"].index)

output = pd.DataFrame()
for frame in list_of_df:
    df = frame[~frame["ElementText"].isin(["Emergency Contacts", "End Employee Line"])].dropna()
    if df.shape[0]>0:
        temp = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("X1")["ElementText"].apply(list).tolist()).T
        temp.columns = temp.iloc[0]
        temp = temp.drop(0)
        output = output.append(temp, ignore_index=True)

>>> output
0       Contact Relationship Work Phone  ...    City  State    Zip
0  Silvia Smith       Mother       None  ...  Austin  Texas  76063
1   Naomi Smith         Aunt       None  ...  Austin  Texas  76063
```